# Setting a cookie upon a button click, postback performs a redirect

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a click event, so when a button gets clicked I save the users drop down list selections to a cookie using the jquery cookie plugin:

```
$.cookie("mycookie", selection_values);
```

When the form submits, on the server-side, I do a redirect:

```
Response.Redirect("/some/url");
```

When I examine the cookie, it seems that sometimes the values are saved and some times they are not.

Is it because the redirect goes to another page and therefore the cookie doesn't save consistently?  Is there a timing issue somewhere?

My code at a high level:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mybutton").click(function() {

    // loop through controls, save to a variable

    $.cookie("mycookie", cookievalues);
  }



  // cookie
  var cookieValue = $.cookie("mycookie");
  if (cookieValue && cookieValue.length) {

       // split cookie values
       // loop through and pre-select drop down lists
  }

});
```

Comment: Can we see a typical run down of the values you're attempting to store in the cookie, and the procedural format at which you've taken to do such.

Comment: you can set your cookie value on the server side instead of using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hidden server control button (inside a div with visibility: hidden;) and then use jquery to 'click' that button after setting cookie inside the 'mybutton'.click function.  This way you can tell if it is a timing issue.